# echo the type of terminal being ran

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to echo the type of the current terminal being ran. For instance If I was running konsole then it would echo konsole. I've tried running

```
echo $TERM
```

But that prints out xterm every time. Is there a better and more accurate way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pstree` can help.

```
$ pstree -s $$
init───gnome-terminal───bash───pstree
```

The `-s` option shows parents of the specified process.

In bash (and Bourne-shell variants), `$$` denotes the PID of the current shell.

Another invocation (while running from `xterm` returns):

```
$ pstree -s $$
init───xterm───bash───pstree
```

Specifying the `-A` option makes `pstree` use ASCII characters so that you can parse the output easily:

```
$ pstree -A -s $$ 
init---gnome-terminal---bash---pstree
```